# Xamarin.Android CustomActionBar(Toolbar) Layout Issue

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've a very interesting issue about xamarin.android in toolbar.
I was created navigation drawer toggle without problem.

After this i need to popup menu so inflated popup menu in 'OnCreateOptionsMenu' of Activity.

Then i saw that problem

[There is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oehob.png)

Activity

```
    mToolbar = FindViewById<SupportToolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    mDrawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        SetSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.ApplicationName);

        mDrawerToggle = new MyActionBarDrawerToggleHelper(
            this,                           //Host Activity
            mDrawerLayout,                  //DrawerLayout
            Resource.String.openDrawer,     //Opened Message
            Resource.String.closeDrawer     //Closed Message
        );

        mDrawerLayout.AddDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle.SyncState();
```

AXML

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px" />
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your layout AXML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set these parameters instead:

```
android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: the issue is comin' from linear layout in toolbar. i forgot to post it. I'm using '@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material' for height. works fine now